# Save model id as foreign key through has_one / belongs_to

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

I'll briefly explain my situation: I have a model called "tax" which belongs_to a "user" and of which a "user" has_one.

In my users table I have a column called "tax_id" which I want to store the id of the tax model when a user creates one.

Currently, in my tax model the create function looks something like this:

```
class Tax < ActiveRecord:Base
belongs_to :user


tax = Tax.new(income: income, taxes: taxes, rrsp: rrsp)
tax.save
```

and then in the taxes_controller file, the create function looks like this:

```
def create
    @tax = Tax.new(secure_params)
    @tax.user = User.find(current_user.id)
    if @tax.save
    redirect_to show_tax_path(current_user.tax)
  else
    render :new
  end
  end
```

(secure_params) being the strong parameters for the field inputs set in a private definition.

Now, someone mentioned that I may have better luck if I use `build` but unfortunately I couldn't get it to work at all, something to do with how I'm using `current_user` (devise). Currently, my setup works just fine, other than saving the tax model id in the user model column "tax_id" like I said.

I'm wondering if I perhaps need to add a foreign ID key to either the belongs_to or has_one statement, even though I was under the impression that the "link" should be made automatically as long as the column was named `"[model]_id"`

Comment: since tax belongs_to user, why you added attribute tax_id in users  table. Instead you should add user_id attribute in taxes table

Comment: @arivarasan I do have user_id in the taxes table, but I want a two way relationship so that the tax_id also gets saved in the users table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using

```
user.build_tax
```

I think this might help you out.

The build syntax for has_many association:

```
user.taxes.build
```

The build syntax for has_one association:

```
user.build_tax  # this will work

user.tax.build  # this will throw error
```

Comment: confused as to where exactly to place the build syntax though? Would it go under the `@tax.user = User.find(current_user.id)` in the create method in the controller, or would it replace the entire method `tax = Tax.new(income: income, taxes: taxes, rrsp: rrsp)` in the model?

Comment: i dont know why you are using this method in model while u can just use it in 'new' method of user and then in the same 'new' method of user you can use "user.build_tax"